# Copy-Item with exclude files and folders in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a question. I want to copy content of one directory into another and made some progress. But, at the moment I'm stuck because if I can define array of files to exclude I have a problem with array of folders. So the arrays looks like:

```
$excludeFiles = @('app.config', 'file.exe')
$excludeFolders = @('Logs', 'Reports', 'Backup', 'Output')
```

It works when there is only one item in $excludeFolders array, but if I add multiple items, it copies all folders without excluding them.

Script I have:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $binSolutionFolder -Recurse -Exclude $excludeFiles | 
where { $excludeFolders -eq $null -or $_.FullName.Replace($binSolutionFolder, "") -notmatch $excludeFolders } |
Copy-Item -Destination {
    if ($_.PSIsContainer) {
        Join-Path $deployFolderDir $_.Parent.FullName.Substring($binSolutionFolder.length -1)
    }
    else {
        Join-Path $deployFolderDir $_.FullName.Substring($binSolutionFolder.length -1)
    }
} -Force -Exclude $excludeFiles
```

Where $binSolutionFolder is source and $deployFolderDir is target.
Files work fine, but with folders I've run out of ideas.

Comment: try replacing `... -notmatch $excludeFolders ...` with `... -notmatch $('^' + ($excludeFolders -join '$|^') + '$') ...`

Comment: Won't work for multi-level subfolders because of anchors, and most likely not at all considering his paths (after substring) would probably start with ` \ `. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-notmatch` uses a regex-pattern and not a collection. To match against a collection of words you could use `-notin $excludedfolders`, but if the path includes 2+ level of folders or just a simple `\` then the test would fail.

I would use `-notmatch`, but first create a regex-pattern that checks all folders at ones. Ex:

```
$excludeFiles = @('app.config', 'file.exe') 
$excludeFolders = @('Logs', 'Reports', 'Backup', 'Output','Desktop')
$excludeFoldersRegex = $excludeFolders -join '|'

Get-ChildItem -Path $binSolutionFolder -Recurse -Exclude $excludeFiles | 
where { $_.FullName.Replace($binSolutionFolder, "") -notmatch $excludeFoldersRegex } |
.....
```